How do we use an Azure Keyvault Private/Public Key for App Registration authentication
I am doing the following:

Generating a key pair using the Azure Keyvault UI
Downloading the public key
Trying to upload that as a certificate in the App Registration UI

I am getting an error that the PEM file isn't a valid certificate.
I have a ticket out to Azure support but I am wondering if anyone else has experienced this and figured out a workaround?

To use Azure Key Vault Private/Public Key for App Registration authentication, check the below:
Go to Azure Key Vaults -> Select your Key Vault -> Certificates -> Generate/Import -> Generate -> Create


Select the certificate and then select the version and set YES for enabled and refresh the page:


To use Key Vault certificate for Azure AD application authentication, you need to download the .CER and .PFX files:


Now, upload the .CER  certificate in the application and .PFX certificate must be in your local system.
The certificate uploaded successfully:

Reference:
asp.net core - Azure Web App use certificate from app registration to authenticate users - Stack Overflow by Qiang Fu

So the answer is that we cannot use the Azure Keyvault Keys for App Registrations?  We have to use the certificate route?
Do you know what the subject has to be for this to work?  I'm trying to create a single authentication mechanism to an App Registration for multiple Azure functions

Yes we have to use certificates

Subject: CN=ExampleDomain check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/quick-create-portal#add-a-certificate-to-key-vault

@NaveenSharma I need to actually test this out to see if it works in my exact situation.

@NaveenSharma I'd also add that the answer provided isn't the answer to my question.  The answer to my question appears to be that I can't but the easiest certificate to use is a self-signed one.  We will see if it actually works once I have time to try it.

Yes you have to use certificates not keys to make it work

@simpleCoder you resolve your issue?

No, I cut a ticket to support and it looks like its being escalated to the team as they also agree that my original approach should work.

It looks like it is currently not an option, but you can vote for my suggestion here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/9a7bc4f6-8518-ef11-9899-6045bd824b24
